# How would I connect to this API from rapidapi in R?

Tags: r, api, rest, httr

I've never connected to an API in R and I am a bit confused on how to just approach it. I am looking to pull flight price data from rapid-api (I have an account) into my R console. Here is the API (to my knowledge) on their website, what script would I start with to connect to this API?

[image]

Comment: I think you do want to delete that screenshot, as it contains your API key!

Comment: The API key is still visible in the code on the right side.

Comment: I disagree with editing the question to remove it ... it's plainly visible in your question history, and it's already out there, you cannot "unring that bell". You need to invalidate that token and create a new one. (And if it were my account, I would add a stern *"Now"*. Over to you :-)

Comment: (BTW: deleting the question will also not get rid of it entirely, in case you were thinking that. It's out there. Bummer, but this is recoverable, *safely*.)

Comment: kill me, okay I will invalidate the token

Comment: FYI, I've been reading https://rapidapi.com/blog/skyscanner-api-overview/curl/ and their examples no longer work, erring with `"path param outboundDate Invalid Date Range provided 2019-01-01"` (on both the command-line and in R). That suggests that the API has been updated somehow and the docs don't really cover it (yet). If you see that error, it might be best to reach out to them directly, since it is what they are recommending. Good luck!

Comment: ohh got it that makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `httr` package has a `GET()` and a `add_header()` function, that let you replicate the functionality I see in the "Code Snippets" tab.

Can't test it, but it should look something like this:

```
library(httr)

GET(
  url = rapidapi_url,
  config = list(x-rapidapi-key = API_KEY,
                x-rapidapi-host = HOST_URL,
                useQueryString = TRUE),
  inboundpartialdate = "2019-12-01"
)
```